# Orthogonality with repsect to Dirichlet solutions of wave eqn. on $[0,T] \times \Omega$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded open set with smooth boundary, and suppose $g(t,x)\in L^1([0,T]; L^2(\Omega))$ such that, for each $t$, $g(t,\cdot)$ is compactly supported in $\Omega$, and $g$ satisfies

$$
\int_0^T \int_\Omega g(t,x) w(t,x) \,dx\,dt = 0
$$

for *every* solution $w$ of the Dirichlet problem (i.e. for any $f \in H^1_0(\Omega), g \in L^2(\Omega)$)

$$
\begin{cases}
    \partial^2_{tt}w - \nabla\cdot(c^2(x)\nabla w) = 0, \\
    w(0,\cdot) = f, \quad w_t(0,\cdot) = g, \\
    w\vert_{\partial\Omega} = 0,
\end{cases}
$$
(you can assume $c\in C^\infty$).

If we had
$$
\int_\Omega G(x) w(t,x) \,dx = 0
$$
for a fixed $t$ and all $w$, we could conclude $G \equiv 0$ as the Dirichlet eigenfunctions form a basis for $L^2(\Omega)$.

- (a) Can we conclude anything similarly here? i.e. is $g(t,x) \equiv 0$?
- (b) If not, does this allow us to draw other conclusions about properties of $g$?

It seems that $g(t,x) \equiv 1$ is a counter-example to (a) in the case $c = 1$, $\Omega = (0,L)$ (as the eigenfunctions in this case all have integral $0$), thus the reason for including the assumption $g(t,\cdot)$ is compactly supported.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured something out, and I'll post in in this answer for posterity, but I would still be happy to see any alternate answers.

If $\lambda_j^2$ are the Dirichlet eigenvalues of $\nabla\cdot(c^2(x)\nabla)$, and $\phi_j$ the corresponding eigenfunctions, then we have

$$
\int\int g(t,x) \phi_j(x) \sin(\lambda_j t) \,dx\,dt = 0 
$$
and
$$
\int\int g(t,x) \phi_j(x) \cos(\lambda_j t) \,dx\,dt = 0
$$

So, if we additionally assume $g(t,x)$ is compactly supported in $[0,T]$ for all $x$,

$$
0 = \int_\Omega \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t,x) e^{i\lambda_j t} \,dt\right) \phi_j(x)\,dx \\
= \int_\Omega \hat g(\lambda_j,x) \phi_j(x)\,dx.
$$

I don't know what further conclusions can be made.